# 301 ht access whole domain on wordpress redirect resulting in - too many redirects

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, http-status-code-301

301 ht access  whole domain on wordpress redirect resulting in - too many redirects

I removed my site from h3adrush.com and placed it on h3adrush.co instead

then

I placed a dummy wordpress site on h3adrush.com and the full original site on h3adrush.co

then

I placed this code on h3adrush.com

Redirect 301 /  http://www.h3adrush.co/

The result when loading h3adrush.com is a redirect to h3adrush.co
but it displays a too many redirects error in the browser
this is not cookie related as I loaded the url through 3 different browsers on 3 different devices

What is the solution to fix this please?
* please explain this to in a simple way so I can follow the steps step by step

Comment: Did you try like this in htaccess? - rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://www.h3adrush.co/$1 [r=301,nc]

Comment: no that does not work it results in the domain being redirected to http://www.h3adrush.com/h3adrush.co/

Comment: @Athia then delete the question if you have solved it.

Comment: I would still like to see the answers of others.